# Automatic type composition and class instantiation

Tags: haskell, type-families

I am developing a library exposing a potentially large number of Consumers, Producers and Effects (from Pipes). They use a ReaderT r ... as the inner monad.

Each component imposes some class constraint (ServerSettings r, FileSettings r, etc.). This is preferable over using concrete types as it propagates when composing components into Effects.

However, users of the library somehow need to create the concrete type, instantiating all required classes that component imposes for that type. This is tedious and might result in 2^(Number of classes) types.

What I want is some type function that for a set of classes, each with a concrete type that instantiates that class, create a type function that creates a composition of those types and instantiates all those classes.

Comment: Your title is just a sequence of tags, and doesn't seem to be strictly related with the question you are asking in your last paragraph. Consider adding a valid title (i.e. an English sentence, not a bunch of unrelated words. Use tags to categorize your question (in fact there exist both the `associated-types` and the `overlapping-instances` tags)) and also adding an example code/pseudo code of what you wanted could clarify what do you mean.

Comment: "This is preferable over using concrete types as it propagates when composing components into Effects." I doubt it; you are rather abusing type classes as OO classes here. You can do that, but as you've noticed it will generally end you up in tedious amounts of instances, likely overlapping. Using concrete types is more to the point, gives you better control, and the amount of boilerplate isn't that bad either since this is Haskell.

Comment: Well, even if all components let r be a concrete type, each composition of components would require a new type which composes both its components types. Let c = Consumer () (ReaderT R1 ..) () and p = Producer () (ReaderT R2 ..) (), then to compose them I would have to create R3 = R3 { r1Field :: R1, r2Field :: R2 } and use withReaderT additionally. I still might end up creating 2^(#SettingsClasses) data types.